# How to iterate values while iterating over nested list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am fetching multiple rows from the database and I am printing rows something like below in nested list and want to fetch each list from nexted list but unable to do so

```
[]
[(Decimal('34535'), datetime.date(2022,9,15)), (Decimal('1456'), datetime.date(2022,9,11)), (Decimal('3455'), datetime.date(2022,10,15))]
[]
```

I have taken care of null scenario by printing 0 rows returned where no rows are retuning but got stuck somewhere while fetching each list for nested loop

```
data = sql.dbconnect(query) # fetching the data from database
count = ['0 rows returned', '0 rows returned'] if data is None else [x for x in lis for x in data] # getting here while writing nested for loop query in one line. need help here
```

expected is I should be able to use count[0] and count[1] to fetch 2 values from a list like

```
count[0] = 34535
count[1] = 2022,9,15

count[0] = 1456
count[1] = 2022,9,11

count[0] = 3455
count(1) = 2022,10,15
```

Comment: `[v for row in data for v in row]`…?!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to return them as strings, from which you can convert to an `int` or `tuple` for the date (if that's your intention).

```
from decimal import Decimal
import datetime

out = [(Decimal('34535'), datetime.date(2022,9,15)), (Decimal('1456'), datetime.date(2022,9,11)), (Decimal('3455'), datetime.date(2022,10,15))]

for o in out:
    count = list(map(str, o))
    print(f'{count[0]=}\n{count[1]=}\n')
```

Output

```
count[0]='34535'
count[1]='2022-09-15'

count[0]='1456'
count[1]='2022-09-11'

count[0]='3455'
count[1]='2022-10-15'
```

A parse function can replace the `str` function above if you do need `int`s and `tuple`s

```
from decimal import Decimal
import datetime

out = [(Decimal('34535'), datetime.date(2022,9,15)), (Decimal('1456'), datetime.date(2022,9,11)), (Decimal('3455'), datetime.date(2022,10,15))]

def parse(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
        return int(obj)
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
        return obj.year, obj.month, obj.day
    return None

for o in out:
    count = list(map(parse, o))
    print(f'{count[0]=}\n{count[1]=}\n')
```

Output

```
count[0]=34535
count[1]=(2022, 9, 15)

count[0]=1456
count[1]=(2022, 9, 11)

count[0]=3455
count[1]=(2022, 10, 15)
```

Comment: Here None typw is not taken care. I have None type also for null values as shown in question which is taken care as 0 rows returned from my side. where can I add that?